# Unit testing for Django login page

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-tests, django-login

I'm currently trying to write unit tests for the built-in django login page, and I keep getting this error.

```
ERROR: test_login_success (User.tests.LoginTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\---------------\User\tests.py", line 74, in test_login_success
    self.assertTrue(response.data['authenticated'])
AttributeError: 'TemplateResponse' object has no attribute 'data'
```

Codes:

no view function because I used the Django built-in login page

```
test.py
def test_login_success(self):
 
        testuser = User.objects.create_user(username = 'howdycowboy', password= 'Testing123' )
        response=self.client.post(self.login_url,{'username':'howdycowboy', 'password': 'Testing123'},format='text/html')
        #self.assertEqual(response.status_code ,302)
        self.assertTrue(response.data['authenticated'])
```

```
#HTML code
{%  extends 'User/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h2>Login</h2>
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

I've also tried `self.assertEqual(response.status_code ,302)`
it redirects once it logs in, but for some reason the response.statuscode is 200.

```
% (response.status_code, status_code)
AssertionError: 200 != 302 : Response didn't redirect as expected: Response code was 200 (expected 302)
```